# Tutorial for installing and configuring a mailserver on CentOS

Tags: centos, command-line-interface, email-server, tutorial

Anybody know of a good howto/tutorial/walkthrough on installing and configuring a mail server on CentOS using the commandline?

I just got myself a fresh VPS.

Last year I used a nice tutorial which basically was a walkthrough of installing / configuring and securing the mailserver and all related stuff, but I forgot the url of course :) .

What do I want:

```
Mail server for CentOS 5.6
IMAP + POP + SMTP
Webmail
Spamfilter
Vscan
anything else?
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asking for tutorials is generally not a good idea, as the tutorials get out of date quickly, and are of little use to future visitors. Instead, if you have a specific question about where you're stuck, feel free to [ask another question](http://serverfault.com/questions/ask) outlining exactly where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, I used the [following tutorial from the CentOS forums](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=4938&forum=31&post_id=14401#forumpost14401).

However, times have changed, and as one of the comments in the above link states, why go through this when there are some more refined packages available. The easiest way to get all of this in a seamless solution is to go with something like [Zimbra Open Source Edition](http://www.zimbra.com/products/zimbra-open-source.html). It puts all of these piece together and provides a more solid webmail interface than most of the other open-source solutions. Consider it...

Comment: And in cases where Zimbra is too heavy (4GB+ of RAM), Citadel would be a lightweight alternative that still provides the ease of setup and use...  http://www.citadel.org/doku.php

Answer (score 0):

This ought to get you started:

http://www.linuxmail.info/mail-server-setup-centos-5/

Comment: No commandline?